# Pass array value from Controller to view by Json after checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a check box in the view, I want it to return data from the controller when checked, it is displayed in the view and displaying in the input boxes?

```
<input  class="js-recipient-is-me" type="checkbox"/>
```

Javascript :

```
$('.js-recipient-is-me').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.js-input-field').addClass('disabled');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Cart/GetUserInfo',
        });
    } else {
        $('.js-input-field').removeClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

Html Inputs :

```
<input type="text" id="mobile" class="js-input-field" name="name" />
<input type="text" id="name" class="js-input-field" name="name" />
<input type="text" id="family" class="js-input-field" name="name" />
```

Controller :

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetUserInfo()
{
    CurrentUserId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

    var userinfo = await _scope.GetUserInfo(Guid.Parse(CurrentUserId));

    return Json(0);
}
```

`userinfo` is a string array and has three values: `["Mobile", "name", "family"]`

I want to put `userinfo` values ​​into inputs...

How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a callback to handle the data received from the server.  You can do this by using `done()` after the `ajax` request.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Cart/GetUserInfo'
    })
    .done( function(data) {
        $('#mobile').val(data[0]);
        $('#name').val(data[1]);
        $('#family').val(data[2]);
    });
```

You also need to pass the data from the Controller to the view. Currently, it looks like you're always returning `0`. Return the `userinfo` object like this: `return Json(userinfo);`

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetUserInfo()
{
    CurrentUserId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var userinfo = await _scope.GetUserInfo(Guid.Parse(CurrentUserId));

    return Json(userinfo);
}
```

---

You should also give your inputs appropriate `name`s - they're all sharing name which would cause issues with a regualar form submission, eg: `<input type="text" id="mobile" class="js-input-field" name="mobile" />`